# Class that extends another class that extends Singleton (pattern) generic class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, subclass

I'm a begginer in unity world, and i'm actually creating a small 2D game here's my problem:

In my project I used Singleton generic class which I found here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

This was perfect until now, I want to create a class which i'll call Parent this class extends Singleton, and each child of Parent must be a singleton, and I want to know how I can do that?

This doesn't work:

```
 public class Parent : Singleton<Parent>{
 protected Parent(){}


 public virtual void method(){
 }

 public  void methidForAllChildes(){
 }

 }

 public class Child : Parent{
     public override void method(){
     }
 }
```

When I call:

```
 (Child.Instance).method();
```

I get Parent.method() instead of Child.method()

Comment: how do you create `Instance`?

Comment: I create `Instance` by calling `Child.Instance` which is defined in `Singleton` class that you can see here [link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) but instead `Parent.Instance` is executed

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your child class is extending `Singleton<Parent>` as illustrated below:

```
Singleton<Parent> <-
    Parent          | inherited from
        Child -------
```

And in `Singleton<T>`, there is a property called `Instance`:

```
public static T Instance {
    get;
}
```

So if your closed generic class is `Singleton<Parent>`, the property would be

```
public static Parent Instance {
    get;
}
```

Which means, `Child` inherited the above property as well. So in `Child`, there is the above declaration implicitly. If you still don't get it, in `Child`, the `Instance` still returns a `Parent`! This is because `Child` is actually inheriting from `Singleton<Parent>`!

Now that you know `Child.Instance` returns a `Parent`, you know why the `Parent`'s `method` is called, because obviously, you are calling from an instance of `Parent`, not `Child`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I send `Child` type to `Singleton` elegantly, to make it `public static Child Instance` when it's a child?